# retrieve record depending on previous record in mysql

Tags: mysql

After getting lots of searches I am not able to find required result.
I have a table *tasktransit* with the following data:

```
+---------------+--------+------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| tasktransitid | taskid | activityid | newsequence | status      | dependency |
+---------------+--------+------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
|             1 | RH001  |          1 |           1 | Not Started |            |
|             2 | RH001  |          2 |           2 | Completed   |            |
|             3 | RH001  |          3 |           4 | Not Started |            |
|             4 | RH001  |          4 |           3 | Not Started |            |
|             5 | RH002  |          3 |           1 | Completed   | NULL       |
|             6 | RH002  |          4 |           2 | Not Started |            |
|             7 | RH003  |          3 |           1 | Not Started | NULL       |
|             8 | RH004  |          4 |           2 | Not Started | NULL       |
+---------------+--------+------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

Here newsequence is unique for one kind of taskid.

```
I want to get the the taskid where 
activityid=4 AND
status="Not Completed" AND
status="Completed" of previous newsequence.
```

Thus With the above kind of sudo code I want a result with the following values

```
taskid    | activityid
 1. RH001  |  4

 2. RH002  |  4
```

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: can you post the schema? and sample data? or put it in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: "Not Completed" or "Not Started"?

Comment: previous newsequence? doesn't match the correct o/p

Comment: Yeah Rupesh, you've messed this up. And what are '1' & '2'?

Comment: And what are '1' & '2': This is nothing during the post I thought to put serial number for the result. Waiting for some positive answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find the status "Not Completed". You added the condition where clause as

```
status="Not Completed" AND status="Completed"
```

Do you want get the list either Not Started OR Completed ?

```
  status="Not Started" OR status="Completed"
```

Comment: I want status="Not Completed" for activityid="4". But at the same time I have to check the newsequence of activity=4 and find previous newsequence, whose status ="Completed".

Comment: select taskid, activityid from `tasktransit` where activityid=4 AND status="Not Completed"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I was not able to convey my question. Along with the above where condition I would also like to check the the previous (whatever the sequence of activityid="4" minus 1) newsequence's status="Completed". –